# How to create different layouts for different screens

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, android-drawable, screen-resolution

I have layout with multiple images i want to show them perfectly on every screen size i have created layout-small,normal,large and xlarge also different drawable folders hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,ldpi but I am confused that which layout use which dpi folder and what images size should i put on different dpi folders.

Anyone please help me to get out of this problem?

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:background="@drawable/main_header"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_menu_copy"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView10"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp" />
```

Thanks

Comment: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ convert the image you want to display to all screen format and use it in application. the above link will help you to convert those.

Comment: visit [Android : Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sur if I understood your question, but for instance on a xlarge device, your app is shiped with layout-xlarge for layout and xhdpi for drawable.

Comment: i have image of size 1517 x 307 px

Answer (score 0):

Please make your layout using different values folder in resource. And make only one or two layout for portrait and landscape layouts. Also make different drawable folder for different size of images.

Please also see the link for more details. [Mobile Design Practice](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/android-design-tips)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio will choose the suitable dpi for you. So you can put every image you have used in each folder your created in different size but same name.
for example:

```
0.75x drawable-ldpi   (120 dpi, Low density screen)        - 36 x 36px<br/> 
1x    drawable-mdpi   (160 dpi, Medium density screen)     - 48 x 48px<br/> 
1.5x  drawable-hdpi   (240 dpi, High density screen)       - 72 x 72px<br/> 
2x    drawable-xhdpi  (320 dpi, Extra-high density screen) - 96 x 96px<br/> 
3x    drawable-xxhdpi (480 dpi,                         )  - 144 x 144px
```

Comment: i have image of size 1517 x 307 px

Comment: Then put that in one folder and build on your screen see if that's the size you want.

Comment: i want this image in all screen size including tabs so i wanna know what size i put in which dpi folder

Comment: You should at least try on phone and adjust it to the size you want. And put the relative size in different folder.